# nodejs formidable typing is inconsistent for Files

Tags: types, next.js, formidable

Using formidable to bypass the fact that nextjs doesn't manage the FormData (in my case to be used when uploading a file)

When calling the root, I'm parsing the body as follows. `Files.File` is typed as `"File | File[]"` although I set `{multiple=false}` when creating the instance of formidable. In my opinion, it should be `File` only as multiple option is set to false.

But the weird thing is that when consoling the files.file object, it is typed as `PersistentFile` and not `File`. And both types are incompatibles....

What is wrong here ?

running "formidable": "^2.0.1", "@types/formidable": "^2.0.0", "typescript": "4.4.4"

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  const form = formidable({ multiples: false });
  form.parse(
    req,
    async (_, fields: formidable.Fields, files: formidable.Files) => {
      console.log(files.file); <--- shows PersistentFile type in the console (see screenshot #2)
      await bucketUpload(
        String(fields.bucketName),
        files.file,
        String(fields.fileName)
      );
    }
  );

  res.status(200).json({ text: "Hello" });
};
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the changelog](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

We have an [open issue about types](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/issues/774)

In v3 files are always an array, so you may want to use it I guess.

Comment: ok will wait for V3 then. thks

Comment: Did you solve your problem by using V3?